# What is this error "AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'load_img'"?

Tags: python, arrays, loops

This is a test function that I have implemented to test POST API call. 
I have added an array with image links that I need loop though.

```
import requests
import json
from keras.preprocessing.image import img_to_array, array_to_img
from keras.preprocessing import image

flowers = ['c:/flower_photos/daisy/107592979_aaa9cdfe78_m.jpg', 'c:flower_photos/daisy/134409839_71069a95d1_m.jpg', 'c:/flower_photos/daisy/144099102_bf63a41e4f_n.jpg','c:/flower_photos/daisy/154332674_453cea64f4.jpg']
for x in flowers:
    image = img_to_array(image.load_img(x, target_size=(128,128))) / 255
    payload = {
      "signature_name": "" ,
      "instances": [{'image': image.tolist()}]
    }
    print("sending request...")
    r = requests.post('http://localhost:8501/v1/models/flowers/versions/1:predict', json=payload)
    print(r.content)
```

The first iteration works fine but then it fails with error "AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'load_img'". What is the attribute error?

```
C:\flowers>client.py
Using TensorFlow backend.
sending request...
b'{\n    "predictions": [[0.895928, 0.0106584, 0.000519791, 0.092504, 0.000389838]\n    ]\n}'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\flowers\client.py", line 8, in <module>
    image = img_to_array(image.load_img(x, target_size=(128,128))) / 255
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'load_img'

C:\flowers>cmd \k
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17763.253]
(c) 2018 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
```

How can I loop this array with POST requests?

Comment: `image = img_to_array(` <-- this overwrites the image module from keras. just use a different name for that variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it's because you're overshadowing `keras.preprocessing.image` due to your variable name in line 8. Replacing it should solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
inp = load_img(file,target_size=(256,256))
inp = img_to_array(inp)
```

use the functions like this. No need to seperately call 'image.AttrName'.